# nodejs - JSONWebToken doesn't expire

Tags: node.js

I have a problem about `jsonwebtoken` when I create a token by using `jwt.sign(data, secret, {expiresInMinutes: 30});`

When I decode this token , it doesn't have elemnet exp and iat. It is only data. So I can't check the expire time of the token.

I don't known why.

Comment: Is data an object or just a string?

Comment: I am using mean io. token is create from a tring

Answer (score 0):

if you are signing a string then the **iat** and **exp** properties will be undefined:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = 'shhh';
var expiration = {
  expiresInMinutes: 30
};

var data = 'wilson';
var token = jwt.sign(data, secret, expiration);
var decoded = jwt.decode(token);

console.log(decoded.iat); // undefined
console.log(decoded.exp); // undefined
```

try signing a JSON data instead:

```
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var secret = 'shhh';
var expiration = {
  expiresInMinutes: 30
};

var data = {name: 'wilson'};  
var token = jwt.sign(data, secret, expiration);
var decoded = jwt.decode(token);

console.log(decoded.iat); // 1434212929
console.log(decoded.exp); // 1434214729
```

Comment: so sorry.  I have solved the problem. I am using Mean.IO , token is created from a string. i have replace to object